# A ring is never a direct sum of infinitely many non-zero left ideals?

Tags: ring-theory

Is it true or false that a ring is never a direct sum of infinitely many non-zero left ideals?

It should be false because we can make a direct product of infinite copies of $\Bbb{R}$, and every copy is a left ideal.

But it was written in a book I was doing. I don't understand the reasoning behind it.

Comment: But the ring is not the direct sum of those ideals. It is the direct product, which is not the same for infinitely many objects.

Comment: The question I think you are thinking of is the one I linked. Of course, if you work with rings without identity, you *can* have a ring that is an infinite "direct sum" of ideals.